# Values of Dropdown in sublist

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am coding an user-event script. I wanted to know :
How can I get all the values in a dropdown field of a sublist in suitescript.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you add some code? Dropdown values are usually stored in a predetermined list I believe...

Comment: where can i get the list of the employees that appear in the event attendee list. In the attendee sublist they are in the column called "Send Invitation to ".

Comment: Check Customizations > Lists, Records & Forms

Comment: Why not do a search instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var options = objField.getSelectOptions({
    filter : 'C',
    operator : 'startswith'
});
```

NETSUITE_DOMAIN/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4435756013.html